# Character.IsWhiteSpace explanation

Tags: java

I was asked to split a string by all chars where `Character.IsWhiteSpace = true`.

Does `Character.IsWhiteSpace` equivalent to:

`c == " " || c == "\t" || c == "\r" || c == "\n"`

**EDIT:**
I'd be glad if you could help think of a neat way to slpit a text by this criteria.

Comment: The source code is available. It's a little more complicated than what you have.

Comment: Of course. But I'm actually asking if those are the only characters considered to be a white-space.

Comment: The source code has the answer to that.

Comment: It is pretty involved. There is no easy answer, but you can look at openjdk's source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/CharacterData01.java#233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to split on such characters is:

```
String[] words = input.split("\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
```

It is documented in the [`Pattern` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> `\p{javaWhitespace}`  Equivalent to `java.lang.Character.isWhitespace()`

In particular, splitting on `\\s` is not equivalent because it will not split on `\u001C...\u001F`.

Answer (score 3):

[Here you can read more about it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29)

Taken from there:

> Determines if the specified character is white space according to
>   Java. A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it
>   satisfies one of the following criteria:

```
It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space ('\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F').
It is '\t', U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION.
It is '\n', U+000A LINE FEED.
It is '\u000B', U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION.
It is '\f', U+000C FORM FEED.
It is '\r', U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN.
It is '\u001C', U+001C FILE SEPARATOR.
It is '\u001D', U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR.
It is '\u001E', U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR.
It is '\u001F', U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.
```

Comment: So, is there a neat way splitting a text by those characters?

Comment: You could use e.g. a `String Tokenizer`. But it depends on what you want to do. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) for an overview.

Comment: `stringToSplit.split("\\s+");`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl That is not the same